# what's the benefits of using gradle on kotlin and android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i'm new on a kotlin developpment, i'm working on a mobile App on android studio and  i use kotlin as language. so i wanted to know  what's the importence of gradle by using tke kotlin and android?

Comment: What do you mean? Most tutorials are written with gradle, and they explain the benefits too. If you prefer not to use gradle, feel free.

Comment: the probleme is what is gradle ? i didn't found a simple explanation on google !

Comment: Gradle is a build system, this is gradles website: https://gradle.org/  Nonetheless you won't need to do much manually, everything is setup and organized by android studio for you. I only find myself editing gradle files to add dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle is the build tool used to build Android apps.

Its responsiblities are managing the dependencies of the project (the library used by your code), to compile the Java/Kotlin code, and to package the final APK with all the compiled code and your app resources (this part is much more complex, but that's a big picture).

Android Studio is using Gradle under the hood for building & running your app.